# How to multiply range of cells by a value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a function where one can enter in an integer representing a percentage to increase by in a certain cell, and then the values a certain range will increased by this input. I'm very new to vba so I'm not quite sure how I can accomplish this. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim percent As Integer

Function ADJUST(percent)
    If percent > 0 Then
        percent = (percent + 100) * 0.01  'Converts value to percentage to increase
        percent.Copy
        Range("K4:N20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
    Else
        percent = 0
    End If
End Function
```

I know the copy & paste special is probably not the most efficient way to do this either. Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? This doesn't require VBA; you're better off to use simple worksheet functions to do this.  If you're unfamiliar with using Excel's worksheet functions, I suggest you focus on that first.

Comment: FYI The `percent` parameter is shadowing the `percent` module-level variable, and the parameter should be declared `As Range`. Also since it's implicitly passed `ByRef`, it's impossible to tell whether the *intent* is to assign `percent` the local-scope parameter, or `percent` the private field at module scope. The module-level variable is not accessible in the `ADJUST` scope. Also unclear: it took me 3 reads to realize the parameter was actually a `Variant/Range`, and that `percent = (expression)` was actually meant to be `percent.Value = (expression)`. Do what you say, say what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a `For` loop and iterate through each cell in the range. Also, note: This doesn't need to be a `Function` as there is no return value - might as well just make it a `Sub` that takes the argument of `percent`.

```
Sub ADJUST(percent)
    If percent > 0 Then
        For Each cell In Range("K4:N20")
            cell.Value = cell.Value * (percent * 0.01)
        Next cell
    Else
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Test:

```
Sub Test()
    Adjust (50)
End Sub
```

[image]

**DISCLAIMER**: Is there a simpler way to do this? Most likely.